# php and bootstrap pass value in action post

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication, bootstrap-4

Hey need help with this 
I'm try to coding simple login page 
and im trying to pass the email and password as post to `login.php`

when I click on submit only send me to the page without "email and password " value

```html
 <div class="logo signin-label fade-in">  <style="width: 100px;"> </div>
   </div>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST" id="Login">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="email id" id="email" type="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="email password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="forgot">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you checking what is sent? where is the php code?  Also you have an extra > in your first div and the divs don't seem to match with open and closing tags.

Comment: name attributes missing.

Comment: You need to use a name attribute in your input tags, like  <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email id" id="email" type="email">. Then in PHP check your $_POST array for $_POST["email"]

Comment: you need a name attribute for every form element to be able to submit with form. ID is for client/css only.

Comment: Thank you so much guys its works as you said before the name attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form field need "name" attribute, please try with this:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" id="Login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="email id" id="email" name="email" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="email password" type="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```